# Globally Modify a global variable within a method Java

Tags: java

I am making Conways Game of Life. In the mouse listener I want the cell to appear/disappear on the screen when I click once. I use a 40x40 boolean array (gameState) of 20x20 pixel cells. I want to paint the squares in my paint method using the co-ordinates of my mouse which i get in its clicked method. However, I am getting a null-pointer exception at line 71 and do not know what to do to solve it.

***Main***

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;

public class mainApplication extends JFrame implements Runnable, MouseListener {


    private static final Dimension windowsize = new Dimension(80, 600);
    private BufferStrategy strategy;
    private Graphics offscreenGraphics;
    private static boolean isGraphicsInitialised = false;
    private static int rows = 40;
    private static int columns = 40;
    private static int height = windowsize.height;
    private static int width = windowsize.width;
    private static Cells cells;
    private int xArrayElement,yArrayElement, xPosition, yPosition;
    private static boolean gameState[][] = new boolean[rows][columns];

    public mainApplication() {
        System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"));

        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Dimension screensize = java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();

        int x = screensize.width / 2 - windowsize.width / 2;
        int y = screensize.height / 2 - windowsize.height / 2;

        setBounds(x, y, screensize.width, screensize.height);

        setVisible(true);

        createBufferStrategy(2);

        strategy = getBufferStrategy();

        offscreenGraphics = strategy.getDrawGraphics();

        isGraphicsInitialised = true;

       // MouseEvent mouseEvent = new MouseEvent();
        addMouseListener(this);
       // addMouseMotionListener(MouseEvent);



        Thread t = new Thread(this);

        t.start();

    }


    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) { }

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) { }

    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) { }

    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) { }

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

        if(e.getClickCount() == 1){

               xPosition = e.getX();
               yPosition = e.getY();

           cells.setPosition(xPosition,yPosition);

            xArrayElement = (xPosition/20);
            yArrayElement = (yPosition/20);

            if(gameState[xArrayElement][yArrayElement]){
                gameState[xArrayElement][yArrayElement] = false;
            }
            else if (!gameState[xArrayElement][yArrayElement]) {
                gameState[xArrayElement][yArrayElement] = true;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
            while (true) {

                try { //threads entry point
                    Thread.sleep(20); //forces us to  catch exception
                }

                catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
            }
        }


    public void paint(Graphics g) {

        if (isGraphicsInitialised) {
            g = strategy.getDrawGraphics();

            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);

            g.fillRect(0, 0, 800, 800);


                    if (gameState[xArrayElement][yArrayElement]) {
                        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                        cells.paint(g);
                    }

                    else if (!gameState[xArrayElement][yArrayElement]) {

                        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                        g.fillRect(xPosition, yPosition, 20, 20);
                    }

                strategy.show();
            }
        }

    public static void main(String[]args){

        mainApplication test = new mainApplication();

    }
}
```

***Cells class***

```
import java.awt.*;

public class Cells {

    int x;
    int y;


    public Cells(){

    }

    public void setPosition(int xi, int xj){

        x = xi;
        y = xi;
        System.out.println(xi);
        System.out.println("sjdkgffdjv" + y);
    }

    public boolean cellState(boolean visible){

        return visible;
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g){

        g.drawRect(x, y, 20,20);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please note that we don't see line numbers here, so it would be helpful to give more specific informations about which line causes the exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @nullPointer has **pointed** out (sorry, dad joke) you're getting a NPE because you haven't initialized the class member Cells. There are also a few other points to make that might unrelated to the question.

1. Don't create that thread

Swing already uses a thread to handle UI events and drawing so creating another thread is dangerous.

2. Make Cells immutable

Cells should be immutable. At no point should you need to set the position of a cell. If you need to change where a Cell is at, just dispose of the object and create a new one at that position.

Comment: I'm 18 and I'm not a dad and I found that funny so dont worry hahaha. I'll intialise the cell object and hope for the best!

Comment: Actually, I'm a college student, I came from general engineering because we had a beginner module for C and I just enjoyed it way more than any other module so I started a bit behind but I'm trying to do my own stuff to keep myself ahead of where I'm expected to be! Also if you dont mind, I intialised it (stupid of me how I missed that) but when I click on the screen to paint, nothing happens. I even have a print statement in the print method but that doesn't even print out, I changed one or two things so I'll repost it again, thanks so much for your help btw!

Comment: Wow, that's really cool that you found a passion from your initial study, that's really lucky! Keeping ahead of the workload is hard but if you keep doing stuff like this it won't be a problem. I did notice that after making some changes that it does draw once, but only once, it doesn't change position. Yeah change a few things and i'll help more!

Comment: Thank you very much! I modified my code, forgot I needed to repaint but for some reason the cells, theyre not painting where I clicked and only one can be present at the time, I uploaded my modified code. Its odd but I'm sure I'll crack it!!!

Comment: @BradleyBrown Make sure you update the description or create a new issue! :)

Answer (score 2):

It's because you haven't initialized your `cells` variable in Main class..
So try this

```
private static Cells cells = new Cells();
```

Comment: Precisely. Good job **nullPointer**. Tbh quite satisfying name for these situations :p.